# SQL: Can I not use COUNT and AVG as aggregate functions when others are not agg?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Okay, next round.
Sorry, for not posting pictures of both code and output before.  Still getting used to how StackOverflow works.
What I'm trying to get is the list of unique customers who started a certain month, the sum of their payments, a count of how many unique customers there are, and an average of their summed payments (total all customers payments divided by the number of customers for that month), grouped by unique customer id.

Can I do all that in the same query, or do I have to break that up into multiple queries?  What other problems am I having?  Feel free to pile on the problems?  I need to know!  thanks!

```
SELECT customer.customer_id AS Jancust_id, 
SUM( payments.payment ) AS Jan_cust_pmts, 
COUNT( DISTINCT customer.customer_id ) AS Jan_orig_cust,
AVG(payments.payment) as CustLifeRev
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
LEFT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer 
ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( customer.account_created_on,  '%Y-%m' ) =  '2016-01'
GROUP BY Jancust_id
```

[image: latest output shot]

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you show your current output, along with what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you need `GROUP BY` in your current query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He's got an aggregate function and a field not being aggregated.  He *absolutely should* have a GROUP BY, even if he's (unwisely) configured MySQL to not require them.

Comment: @BaconBits Then he should be grouping by the month perhaps, I think he wants the number of unique customers in January.  Do you see that his current grouping doesn't make any sense?

Comment: It looks to me like you're confused about the type of JOIN you should use, and running into problems with your WHERE clause eliminating records that you don't think should be eliminated.  However, you never explain what your query is *supposed* to do; neither do you supply any sample data or expected outcome.  How should we know what you're trying to return?  We're not mind readers.

Comment: As @Bacon said, you should really include sample data and output here.  I have a couple of ideas, but without this they are just guesses.

Comment: Thanks Bacon and Biegelsen, I'm still adjusting to going to the community as help idea (rather late to the game I know, but them's the breaks!)  your leniency and patience is appreciated.  TBH, 'm uncertain about multiple parts of this.   Still working out the particulars of multiple functions.

Comment: Yes, the number of unique customers initiated in January is what I was looking for in the count in the first query.  Then in the second, the number of unique customers that made a payment was being counted in the second query.

Comment: If you remove the `customer.customer_id AS Jancust_id` as `GROUP BY` the same you're there I think

Comment: sorry - remove `customer.customer_id AS Jancust_id` in the select *and* `GROUP BY` is what I meant.

Comment: Many people find LEFT JOIN hard enough to understand, and RIGHT JOIN utterly confusing... Do yourself and everybody else a favor, consider a switch to LEFT JOIN. (`main table left join optional data` is much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.)

Answer (score 0):

I sense that you are trying to aggregate over customers, and hence you thought that specifying the `customer_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause was appropriate.  Actually, the aggregate functions `SUM()` and `COUNT()` which you were using will implicitly aggregate over customers.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(payments.payment) AS Jan_cust_pmts,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer.customer_id) AS Jan_orig_cust
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
RIGHT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer 
    ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE customer.account_created_on BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
```

As @LordBaconPants mentioned, in many databases you cannot use `SUM()` in this way without `GROUP BY`.  In your case, grouping by month would be appropriate.  We could rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(payments.payment) AS Jan_cust_pmts,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer.customer_id) AS Jan_orig_cust,
       DATE_FORMAT(customer.account_created_on, '%Y-%m') AS year-month
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
RIGHT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer 
    ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(customer.account_created_on, '%Y-%m') = '2016-01'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(customer.account_created_on, '%Y-%m')
```

You can remove the `WHERE` clause from the above query to generate a monthly report.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm basically trying to meld your approach with mine.  What I really is want each unique customer_id with a summary of payments made, and a count of the total unique customer_id that was created within that month.  I'm playing around with yours combined with some modifications to the original code I posted.  Thanks

Comment: @herbacidal This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  If you had posted some sample data and your expected output, you'd probably have an answer already.  Please post some data.